# MATLAB IF statement

Tags: matlab

Im a new MATLAB user. Trying to initialize y to the calculated value in the if statement. However, when I try to plot y it says y not defined

```
function [y,xmax] = Alaw(x,A,ymax)

if nargin<3, ymax=1; end
if nargin<2, A=87.6; end


xmax=max(abs(x)); 

    temp = ymax/A;
if ((x > 0) & ( x < temp ))
    y = (A * abs(x)) ./ (1 + log(A) ).*sign(x);
end    

if (x > temp)
    y = ymax*( 1 + log(A*abs(x/ymax)) )./( 1+log(A) ).*sign(x);
end


 fprintf('Plotting Data ...\n');
 hold on;
 figure;
 plot(y);
 xlabel('x-axis');
 ylabel('y-axis');
 title('  A LAW ');

 pause;
 fprintf('Writing the audio file ...\n');
 wavwrite(y, 22050, 'Alaw.wav');


 end
```

Comment: What are `x` and `temp`? You may not be reaching the body of either `if` statement. In that case, `y` would never get created.

Comment: X is a vector provided during function call. Temp is calculated ass shown

Answer (score 4, accepted):

If `x` is smaller than or equal to zero, or if `x` equals `temp`, neither of the if-statements is true, and thus, `y` never gets defined. You may want to re-write the logic with `if..elseif..else` to ensure that `y` gets assigned in every case:

```
if ((x > 0) & ( x < temp ))
    y = (A * abs(x)) ./ (1 + log(A) ).*sign(x);
elseif (x > temp)
    y = ymax*( 1 + log(A*abs(x/ymax)) )./( 1+log(A) ).*sign(x);
else
    y = NaN(size(x)); % no valid y; this won't plot anything, but won't error
end
```

Note that `x>0` can lead to unexpected results when `x` is an array. Use `all` or `any` to make sure that the condition is satisfied if either all or any of the elements of `x` satisfy the condition, respectively.

Comment: I made a few changes. Because i want to go thorugh every element of vector and then decide what operation to do so i must use a loop.

'code'
    while (i<length(x))
    
    if ((x(i) > 0) & ( x(i) < temp ))
        y = (A * abs(x(i))) ./ (1 + log(A) ).*sign(x(i));
    end    
    
    if (x(i) > temp)
        y = ymax*( 1 + log(A*abs(x(i)/ymax)) )./( 1+log(A) ).*sign(x(i));
    end
    
    i=i+1;
    end     
 
But this way i dont get the plot

Comment: @user905911: even if you run it for individual elements, you should use if/elseif/else. Also, you need to assign each element of `y`, i.e. `y(i)=...`.

Answer (score 0):

Works for me:

```
>> Alaw([1 2 3])
Plotting Data ...

ans =

1.0000    1.1267    1.2007
```

[image]